# Unable to link inaction and view controller in Xcode 6.1.1

Tags: xcode, swift, storyboard, viewcontroller, ibaction

**Xcode 6.1.1** - I have written small apps with a button. I have written `IBAction`  method `showMessage()` in ViewController.swift. When I was trying to connect button and view controller. The View Controller icon in storyboard didn't show the **"Sent Event"---> showMessage** method.

```
@IBAction func showMessage() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome to My First App", message: "Hello World", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Please show the code for your `IBAction` method.

Comment: are you sure that you set your viewcontroller to the class in the storyboard?

Comment: @IBAction func showMessage() {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome to My First App", message: "Hello World", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

Answer (score 0):

Your method is fine.  When I tried it, it worked and `showMessage` did show up under *Sent Events*.  As @Daniel Nagy alluded to in the comments, you should make sure you set your class correctly in the Storyboard.

1. Click on the ViewController icon at the top of your View Controller.
2. In the Identity Inspector on the right, set the **Class** to the Class of your View Controller.

   [image]

Comment: 0down voteaccept 

Thanks. I have noticed that the Module field is empty. It is not filled with my project name such as "Current - HelloWorld"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I have noticed that the Module field is empty. It is not filled with my project name such as **Current - HelloWorld**